# MYSQL variables - SET @var

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, variables, duplicate-data

I am attempting to create a MySQL snippet that will analyse a table and remove duplicate entries (duplicates are based on two fields not entire record)

I have the following code that works when I hard code the variables in the queries, but when I take them out and put them as variables I get MySQL errors, below is the script:

```
SET @tblname = 'mytable';
SET @fieldname = 'myfield';
SET @concat1 = 'checkfield1';
SET @concat2 = 'checkfield2';

ALTER TABLE @tblname ADD `tmpcheck` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;

UPDATE @tblname SET `tmpcheck` = CONCAT(@concat1,'-',@concat2);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_table` (
`tmpfield` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

INSERT INTO `tmp_table` (`tmpfield`) SELECT @fieldname FROM @tblname GROUP BY `tmpcheck` HAVING ( COUNT(`tmpcheck`) > 1 );

DELETE FROM @tblname WHERE @fieldname IN (SELECT `tmpfield` FROM `tmp_table`);

ALTER TABLE @tblname DROP `tmpcheck`;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@tblname ADD `tmpcheck` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL' at line 1
```

Is this because I can't use a variable for a table name? What else could be wrong or how would I get around this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this because I can't use a variable for a table name?

Yes, or for other schema names like columns. String variables can only be used where MySQL expects a `'`-quoted string.

If you really need to do this you can with ‘dynamic SQL’: creating your whole query as a string, concatenating the `@tblname` into the string at that time, and executing the lot using [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execute.html). This is pretty ugly and can lead to SQL-injection if you're not careful, so avoid it if there is any other option.

> SELECT myfield FROM mytable GROUP BY `tmpcheck` HAVING ( COUNT(`tmpcheck`) > 1 )

This seems problematic to me. Unless `myfield` has a functional dependency on `tmpcheck` (which AFAICS it can't, as `tmpcheck` is not a primary key), that's not valid ANSI SQL. MySQL would let you get away with it, but what you would be saying is “for each group of rows sharing a value of `tmpcheck`, pick the `fieldname` from one row out of that group *at random* for later deletion”. Is that really what you want? I would expect you to want to delete *all but one* of the duplicates.

Normally you shouldn't need this kind of complicated procedure to remove duplicates. Just use a DELETE-join:

```
DELETE my0
FROM mytable AS my0
JOIN mytable AS my1
    ON my1.checkfield1=my0.checkfield1 AND my1.checkfield2=my0.checkfield2
    AND my1.id>my0.id;
```

This is assuming an `id` field that is orderable and `UNIQUE` so that you can decide which row gets to stay (here, the one with the highest `id`). `myfield` might be that field, but I can't tell from context.

Answer (score 1):

Using a variable for the table name is indeed illegal. You'll have to generate the SQL as a string and use [the prepared statement feature](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) to execute it.

Comment: I have now tried PREPARE stmt_name FROM "ALTER TABLE ? ADD `tmpcheck` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL";
SET @tblname = 'mytable';
EXECUTE stmt_name USING @tblname;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_name;

But get an error at the '?'

Comment: The same rule about not being able to use variables for table names likely goes for statement parameters. Concatenate the table name in with CONCAT() instead of making it a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a combination of both answers:

```
SET @tblname = 'myTable';
SET @idfield = 'myPrimaryKey';
SET @check1 = 'field1';
SET @check2 = 'field2';

SET @q1 = CONCAT('DELETE my0 FROM `',@tblname, '` AS my0 JOIN `',@tblname, '` AS my1 ON my1.',@check1,' = my0.',@check1,' AND my1.',@check2,' = my0.',@check2,' AND my1.',@idfield,' > my0.',@idfield,'');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @q1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```